# Different results on the same dataset in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I use the scikit-learn library for the machine learning (with text data). It looks like this:

```
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', tokenizer=nltk.word_tokenize, stop_words=stop_words).fit(train)
    matr_train = vectorizer.transform(train)
    X_train = matr_train.toarray()
    matr_test = vectorizer.transform(test)
    X_test = matr_test.toarray()
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
    rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_predict = rfc.predict(X_test)
```

When I run it for the first time, the result for the test dataset is 0.17 for the recall and 1.00 for the precision. Ok.
But when I run it for the second time on this test dataset and this training dataset the result is different - 0.23 for the recall and 1.00 for the precision. And when I'll run it for the next times the result will be different. At the same time the precision and the recall for the training dataset are one and the same.

Why does it happen? Maybe this fact refers to something about my data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A random forest fits a number of decision tree classifiers on various sub-samples of the dataset. Every time you call the classifier, sub-samples are randomly generated and thus different results. In order to control this thing you need to set a parameter called `random_state`.

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=137)
```

Note that `random_state` is the seed used by the random number generator. You can use any integer to set this parameter. Whenever you change the `random_state` value the results are likely to change. But as long as you use the same value for `random_state` you will get the same results.

The `random_state` parameter is used in various other classifiers as well. For example in Neural Networks we use `random_state` in order to fix initial weight vectors for every run of the classifier. This helps in tuning other **hyper-parameters** like **learning rate**, **weight decay** etc. If we don't set the `random_state`, we are not sure whether the performance change is due to the change in **hyper-parameters** or due to change in initial weight vectors. Once we tune the **hyper-parameters** we can change the `random_state` to further improve the performance of the model.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Irshad Bhat Not sure if I should ask a new question. What if the accuracy metrics are too sensitive to the random_state / np.random.seed()?  I can understand small variations in accuracy metrics as a result of some level of randomness inherent in the models. Differences as large as 20-30% in accuracy metrics is a bit worrying.  Is this telling us something about the nature of the features and the target variable used to build the model?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is (at least partly) in the name.

A Random Forest uses randomised decision trees, and as such, each time you fit, the result will change.

https://www.quora.com/How-does-randomization-in-a-random-forest-work